# The problem of dependencies management

Tags: c#, architecture, .net, enterprise-architecture

Let's consider the next situation:

1. We have a module A which has a class Crt570 intended to interact with a device.
2. We have a module B which uses Crt570 in the class called M100Communicator.
3. We have two applications C and D and both of them wants to use module B.
4. Application D wants to use B, but doesn't want to use Crt570 and reference module A, therefore.

"Module" here means dll.

So we decided to extract an interface from Crt570 and called it ICrt570.
But what to do with that now? It's just very strange to move ICrt570 into the domain module (let's call it module E) or somewhere else because after that Crt570 has to reference the module which will contain ICrt570!

How to solve the puzzle?

**UPDATE**
In order to make the question more clear for readers in the future I'll add a bit more details.

Module A is the dll which contains nothing but Crt570 class (with it's infrastructure). So this dll is dedicated to manage a device absolutely, nothing more.

Module B is the dll which contains models specific for several applications in our domain.
At least 3 applications want to use this module and they, of course, don't want to pull dll's they don't need.

One of the models that C and D apps want to use is the M100Communicator model. And, in particular, this class (M100Communicator) depends on module A (Crt570 class).

Module E which I mentioned is a domain module. It contains many classes and interfaces, so module A doesn't want to use it, apparently.

Comment: The problem is a common one, but I don't think there is enough here to give a good answer. And the use of 'module' is not obvious.

Comment: "Module" means dll here. So can you offer something?

Comment: I'm kind of stuck on the bit where B uses Crt570 and D wants to use B without using Crt570. Sounds like you need some basic refactoring/layering/IOC stuff.

Comment: I assume that Crt571 in the update is supposed to be Crt570?

Comment: Yes, it is, you are right)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As david.pfx writes in his comment, there is a bit of info missing, but I am willing to give it a shot.

I am making an assumption in my answer.

- The reason that C and D both want to use B is, at least in part, to use `M100Communicator`

Thereafter it kinda depends on if other modules are around that want to use the `ICrt570` interface.

**Scenario A**

If it is only module B that needs to interact with your interface, you could define it there. Then the two `C` and `D`, could give `M100Communicator` each an implementation of `ICrt570`.

1. `C` References `A and B` Giving `Crt570 from A` to `M100Communicator` as the implementation of `ICrt570` to be used. (A would also have to reference B since it is implementing an interface defined there)
2. `D` References only `B`. Since `M100Communicator`needs an `ICrt570`implementation it still has to supply this. Either it has to make an implementation itself or reference another module with an implementation.

**Scenario B**

If, on the other hand other modules than `B` are going to have a dependency on `ICrt570`, then you would need to move it to some other module, maybe even its own.

You could define the module `E`as you mention, containing `ICrt570`. This module's reason for living is to be the "Device communications interface module". This module defines interfaces, nothing else.

Then all the others can reference this module: `A` to implement the interface, `B`to have a dependency on it. `C and D` so they know what `ICrt570` is. Since this module is only interfaces there isn't much "harm" in referencing it.

C and D are now free to choose whichever implementation of ICrt570 that they want. Same goes for X, Y, Z who also use `ICrt570` in some way.

**A couple of points**

- References are not necessarily bad, only if the modules you reference have a lot of different stuff you don't want. Then you might have a problem with `The Single Responsibility Principle`, your modules might be doing too much.
- Something that helped me better understand dependency management with low coupling, was to study the [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) by Jeffrey Palermo. He takes the whole thing very far, some might say too far. But the principles of low coupling, dependency injection etc. are explained very well in his blog posts.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of answer I would give if I thought I had enough information to give an answer.

Comment: Taking into account my update I'll presume that Scenario B is more suitable for the problem I described. Am I right?

Comment: I cannot give you an absolute answer, it always depends on the full design. But ye,s with my understanding of your problem, I would probably go with a Scenario B-like design. 
Seems to me though, that some refactoring towards being more SOLID might be needed.

Software design is always weighing a bunch of pros and cons. There is rarely a "One true answer" that works in every problem domain.

Comment: I'm for Scenario A. Here ICrt570 is interface that M100Communicator uses to define what functionality it needs to function. So it is closely tied to this interface. Having this interface in separate module would break this relationship.

Comment: @Euphoric, the problem with this approach is that Crt571 will need to reference module B and this is not right. Module B contains a lot of specific application models. However, Crt571 should be separately deployable (and scenario B fits this requirement).

Comment: @EngineerSpock "and this is not right" how so? It fits right into Dependency Inversion Principle. "Crt571 should be separately deployable" What does that mean? Do you have code other than M100Communicator that uses this Crt571?

Comment: @Euphoric, well, not right now))) But it's very strange to me to be able to access tons of WTF classes of module B from Crt570 dll.

Comment: @EngineerSpock If we assume that module B contains abstract application policy, then it is not weird that module A, which implements details of this the policy, depends on it. Because implementation details are more likely to change than abstract policy. And dependencies follow this likeness to change. That actually makes application modular, extensible and SOLID.